# Using d3.js v3 and v4

Tags: d3.js

I wonder if it is possible to use d3.v4 and  d3.v3 at the samme time by renaming the global object d3 for example? I swchited to v4 but I need to merge a v3 and v4 project. I would like to rename v4 and use it independently. Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Why not refactor the d3 version 3 project to use d3 version 4?

Comment: I will but it will take time and I use dc.js.

Comment: In fact I just rename d3 in d3v4 in the source file and it works. I hope it wiill help someone